# Wordpress Plugin doesn't load JS files

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am writing my first plugin for wordpress and I'm attempting to load scripts in with my plugin.

```
function somadome_enqueue_script() {   
    wp_enqueue_script( 'somajQuery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js',array(), '1.0');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'logoslickjs', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/slick.js',array('jQuery'), '1.0');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'logoslider', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/somaslick.js',array('jQuery'), '1.0');
    wp_enqueue_style('slickcss', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/css/slick.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('logocss', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/css/somaslide.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
}

/*Create Plugin Parts*/
add_action('init', 'create_carousel');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'somadome_enqueue_script');
```

The issue is the CSS loads (two lines at the bottom) but the code at the top (the scripts) doesn't Load and I'm trying to figure out why the Javascript/JQuery code isn't loading.

I echo'd the paths to check them and they load into the browser fine, so they exist. But aren't being loaded by wordpress.

Comment: What do you mean by “loaded into the browser fine…but aren't being loaded by wordpress.”? If loaded all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the code, I'm assuming it's not loading because you've missed the forward slash from the JavaScript files in the enqueue function.

```
function somadome_enqueue_script() {   
    wp_enqueue_script( 'somajQuery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js',array(), '1.0');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'logoslickjs', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/js/slick.js',array('jQuery'), '1.0');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'logoslider', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/js/somaslick.js',array('jQuery'), '1.0');
    wp_enqueue_style('slickcss', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/css/slick.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('logocss', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/css/somaslide.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
}
```

...should get things working.

Comment: It's odd, I tried that on the test server I had running. But i guess that PHP files are cache'd, especially since I use chrome. Thank you, this helped solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess its just a dependencies issue. You've set your `logoslickjs` depends on `array('jQuery')` and The dependencies argument of wp_enqueue_script() is case sensetive, so it should be `array('jquery')`

But, since you're loading a custom version of jQuery called `'somajQuery'`, you need to change the script depends `array('jQuery')` to `array('somajQuery')` so your code should be:

```
function somadome_enqueue_script() {   
    wp_enqueue_script( 'somajQuery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js',array(), '1.0');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'logoslickjs', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/js/slick.js',array('somajQuery'), '1.0');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'logoslider', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/js/somaslick.js',array('somajQuery'), '1.0');

    wp_enqueue_style('slickcss', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/css/slick.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('logocss', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/css/somaslide.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
}
```

Now, `logoslickjs` and `logoslider` are depends on custom jQuery `somajQuery` and so on.